# A function such that $f(z)=f(z/|z|)$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f: \Bbb{C} \setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb{C}$ is a function such that $f(z)=f(z/|z|)$ and its restriction to the unit circle is continuous, then which one is true:

1. $f$ is continuous but not necessarily analytic;
2. $f$ is analytic but not necessarily constant;
3. $f$ is a constant function;
4. $\lim \limits_{z\to 0} f(z)$ exists.

Since the value of $f$ can be obtained from its value on unit cicle, so by the given condition $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{C} \setminus\{0\}.$ But I am not able to think of such an example of a function to conclude others option are correct or not. Please someone help.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon But $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$ is simply irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Just saw that $0$ is not in the domain, apologies.

Comment: "$f$ is continuous all over $\Bbb{C}$." No, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$

Comment: @zwh sorry,basically  I want to tell its continuous all over the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of examples.  Starting with @zhw's observation, here are a few:

$\cos \theta = \cos z/|z|,$

$\sum a_k (z/|z|)^k,$

any constant.

I think it is easy to prove that the "answer" is 1:  $f$ continuous and not necessarily analytic.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(z)=z/|z|$ satisfies the hypotheses.